# How to expose an enum value in RestAPIs

Tags: json, rest, kotlin, enums, mapstruct

There is an enum class `Size`:

```
enum class Size {
    SMALL("1-50"),
    MEDIUM("51-1000"),
    LARGE("1001-5000"),
    EXTRA_LARGE("5000+");
}
```

How to return this to consumers of this API? In case I'd return i.e. `"1-50"` then we cannot use this same JSON to make a `PUT` for instance, because it's an invalid value. The expected value is `SMALL`, so does it mean that we should return `SMALL` but the consumer must inform their clients that SMALL means 1-50 in this case? What is the best practice to handle that? I thought also to use `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)` and return the enum and the display value. The display value could be used for the UI, but the enum name for updates via a `PUT` method.

What are the best practices for that, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that in your case, the best option is exactly to use `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)`. With this, you provide every information that might be needed by the consumers and they have all the needed data to be able to display understandable information and to call your API again when the `Size` enum is needed.

The other options (returning `1-50` and then expecting `SMALL` or simply returning `SMALL`) pushes your business logic to the consumers, because in the first case it would then require the consumer to know that `1-50` matches `SMALL` and that is the value that should be sent in the `PUT` and in the second case it would require the consumer to know that `SMALL` matches `1-50` and that is the value that should be displyed.